# React component is rendering old state before getting new data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

When the component first renders it gets from the switchcase (enters ALL case because its the default value) on the usePositions hook, the value for positions and I set them there, and return them to the Positions controller.

The problem comes when the selectedClient changes from ALL to TODAY (its a context value, I change it in a Sidebar component somewhere else) and before entering the switch case in TODAY value to get the positions of today, I noticed the Positions component already rendered the old state of ALL positions again! Then a second later it renders correctly the todays positions.

I noticed this because my browser on my network tab shows some calls to the server that IndividualPosition makes it means that it rendered

This is my component where it calls the usePositions hook

```
export const Positions = () => {
  const { selectedClient } = useSelectedClientValue();
  const { loading, setLoading } = useLoadingValue();
  const { positions } = usePositions(selectedClient);
  const clientName =
    typeof selectedClient === "string" ? selectedClient : selectedClient.name;

  useEffect(() => {
    setLoading(false);
  }, [positions]);

  let positionsView = (
    <ul className="positions__list">
      {positions.map((position) => (
        <IndividualPosition position={position} key={position.positionId} />
      ))}
    </ul>
  );

  return (
    <div className="positions" data-testid="positions">
      {!loading ? (
        <>
          <div className="positions__header">
            <h2 data-testid="client-name">{clientName}</h2>
          </div>
          {positionsView}
        </>
      ) : (
        <div className="loading-main-window">
          <Spinner />
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};
```

This is the hook where I fetch the data

```
export const usePositions = selectedClient => {
    const [positions, setPositions] = useState([]);
    const {setLoading} = useLoadingValue()
    useEffect(() => {
        setLoading(true);
            switch (selectedClient) {
                case 'ALL':
                    getPositions().then(pos => {
                            setPositions(pos);
                    });
                    break;
                case 'TODAY':
                    getTodayPositions().then(pos => {
                            setPositions(pos);
                    });
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }, [selectedClient]);
    return {positions, setPositions};
};
```

The useEffect runs each time the selectedClient change

It looks like the component renders again before getting the todays data and thats why it shows the old state before getting the new data, but I thought that could be avoided with the loading flag

Basically:

-Positions renders, the hook fetches allPositions, its fine
-If I change in the sidebar the value of the selectedClient context value, the Positions components renders again, rendering the IndividualComponent but with the state of allPositions.
- Instead it should wait till todaysPositions fetches to show the new state (loading should do that)

I already tried having a loading local state (my loading is a context value)
Moving the loading in the useEffects on my local component instead of my hook
Setting loading to false inside the hook after fetching the data

Any ideas?

Comment: Is Positions a child of any other component?

Comment: Just from the App component and Providers